# Basic if else statements

Tags: c++

Consider this code that I have written which uses and `if` `else` statement

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a = 5;
    if(a)
    {
        printf("if %d\n" , ++a);
    }
    else
        printf("else %d\n" , a);
}
```

If I set `int a = 5` it prints outputs "if 6"

But if I set `int a = 0` it prints the value "else 0"

Why is it happening what is the reason?

Comment: Can you be more specific about which part is confusing you?

Comment: What do you think `if(a)` should do?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux  Part I am confused is with  Why does it increments the a value to 6 in the if statement when int a =5 . and when i replace the same int a = 0 it prints else 0

Comment: @SayliJawale The reason `a` is incremented is because of the `++` [increment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec). `++a` is equivalent to `a = a + 1`.

Comment: @SayliJawale: I believe my answer covers all this. If it's too terse then do let me know.

Comment: @SayliJawale don't post code in comments, it's unreadable. Edit your question or post another question.

Comment: Amazing that you don't understand the behavior that you wrote yourself ! Compare what you wrote in the "if" and "else" clauses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`++a` increases the value of `a` by one and is an expression that equals that incremented value.

1. When `a` is 5, `if (a)` is `if (true)` as `a` is non-zero. So `printf("if %d\n" , ++a);` runs, the `++a` in that statement increments `a` and evaluates to that incremented value, 6.
2. When `a` is 0, `if (a)` is `if (false)`. So `printf("else %d\n" , a);` runs. `a` is not changed in that case.

Comment: Great explanation, thanks for helping the newcomers.

Comment: I got to know about the increment value but What i am not understanding is  the why is it printing 0  , while my int a =0 , why not it is incrementing with 1?

Comment: for example int a=5 , if it is incrementing  ++a , It will work out in this way a+1 = 5+1 =6  , why cant the same be applied to int a =0 , as in a+1 = 0+1 =1? so why in this case is it not increased to 1

Comment: if `a` is 5, then `++a` is 6, and `a` is also increased to 6.

Comment: @SayliJawale thats because you are setting a to 0,  so your a is 0 the `if(a)` code doesn't run so it doesnt get incremented only the code in your `else` statement is ran.

Comment: @SayliJawale if `a` is `0` then the statement that is executed is `printf("else %d\n" , a);` This statement *does not have* the increment operator.

Comment: I think really from this point, your line-by-line debugger should take over.

Comment: Does that means   if(0) , it is false , so it returns me 0? AM i getting it correct?

Comment: @Sayli ++a and a++ will increment the value of a. in a printf statement ++a will run before the print, therefore by the time it prints the value of a it is 6, in a statement with a++ it will print the value of a before the ++, but after that statement the a is value 6.  if you run a print statement without a++ or ++a the value of a isnt incremented at all.

Comment: @SayliJawale if your a is 0 then the first statement will not be ran, since 0 would equate to false.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what is going on is confusion understanding whats happening with the if statement.

```
int main() {
    int a =5;
    if(a)
    {
        printf("if %d\n" , ++a);
    }
    else
        printf("else %d\n" , a);
    return 0;
}
```

This code is essentially equivalent to:

```
int main() {
    int a =5;
    printf("if %d\n" , ++a);
    return 0;
}
```

> output: 6

If a was 0 the code would be equivalent to:

```
int main() {
    int a =0;
    printf("else %d\n" , a);  // Notice no ++
    return 0;
}
```

> output: 0

If you were to write the code as:

```
int main() {
    int a =5;
    printf("if %d\n" , a);  // Notice no ++
    return 0;
}
```

> output: 5

`if` Will evalute the value stored in the parenthesis so for example:

```
int a = 0;
if(a)  // since a is 0, the value equates to false and the if is ignored
{

}
else // since the if evaluated to false it will do the else.
{
 
}
```

In the instance of:

```
int a = 5;
if(a) // a is non-zero therefore it equates to true, and the if body is ran
{

}
else // since the if was true the else is ignored, and its body wont be run.
{
 
}
```

Now lets breakdown why in your case a = 5 was printing out 6.

In c++, there are operators called `postfix` and `prefix` operators, postfix operators will run after the statement whereas prefix operators will run before the statement.

These operators will directly affect the value.

> ++a - prefix operator, gets resolved before your printf and retrieves the value.
>
> a++ - postfix operator, retrieves the value and then gets resolved after your printf
>
> a - no operator just retrieves the value.

You can learn more about these operators here:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec

Bathsheba, answer is 100% correct.  Posted this answer to try and attempt to further your understanding, and anyone else who comes here with the same issues.

Comment: Thank you for clearing the true false concept  here in If -Else now I clearly understood how and Why is it working and printing 0 While taking int a=0

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code modified slightly to show the two cases you are asking about.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a;

    a = 5;
    if(a)   // check whether a is zero (false) or non-zero (true)
    {
        // variable a has a non-zero value (true)
        printf("if %d\n" , ++a);  // preincrement variable a then print value
    }
    else {
        // variable a has a value of zero (false)
        printf("else %d\n" , a);  // print value as it is
    }

    a = 0;
    if(a)   // check whether a is zero (false) or non-zero (true)
    {
        // variable a has a non-zero value (true)
        printf("if %d\n" , ++a);  // preincrement variable a then print value
    }
    else {
        // variable a has a value of zero (false)
        printf("else %d\n" , a);  // print value as it is
    }

    return 0;
}
```

There is a difference between preincrement of a variable, using ++a, and postincrement of a variable, using a++.

Preincrement, the ++a, increments the value of the variable and makes the new value available for the next operator or action.

Postincrement, the a++, makes the current value of the variable available for the next operator or action and then increments the variable.

So look at the following code.

```
int  a;
int  b;

a = 5;
b = a;    // straight assignment, no increment, b now contains 5.
b = a++;  // postincrement a, do assignment, b now contains 5, a contains 6
b = ++a;  // preincrement a, do assignment, b now contains 7, a contains 7
```

Now in your code you first assign a value of 5 to the variable `a`. When you do the `if` you check to see if `a` is true (value is non-zero) or false (value is zero). Since `a` equals 5, value is non-zero, then it takes the `then` path.

When it does the `printf()` the value of `a` is modified using a preincrement. This means that the value of `a` is first incremented and then the new value of `a` is used in the `printf()`. So you print the value of the preincremented variable `a` which is 6 printing "if 6".

If you had used a postincrement then the old value of `a` would have been used in the printf()` printing "if 5".

Next you set the value of the variable `a` to zero. The if checks whether `a` is true, non-zero, or false, zero, and since `a` is now zero or false the path taken is the `else`. In this `printf()` you are just printing the value of the variable `a` so you see "else 0".

Comment: Thanks For explaining the concept of post increment and pre increment. also the non-zero value now I Completely understood this